# Java - Replacing characters in the string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if statement that checks if a string contains the character `/`.

If contained, it will be replaced with `\\`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that.

Comment: See the [API docs of class `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Beware that backslash is a special character in Java source code and that you need to escape it by using double backslash.

Comment: Can you imagine the world if you couldn't make such an operation in java ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=string+replace+java

Comment: On a side note. If you would have taken the time to type the title of this post into google, it comes up with a TON of results on exactly how to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way to do this is to use the `replaceAll()` method of String and a regular expression:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("/", "\\\\");
```